# crmsvcutil error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I get the following error when generating early bound entities

Exiting program with exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Enable tracing and view the trace files for more information.

The command I run is

```
crmsvcutil.exe /out:"..\Entities.cs" /namespace:XXXX.CRM.Model.Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext /codewriterfilter:"XXX.CRM.Util.SvcUtil.Extensions.EntityFilteringService, XXX.CRM.Util.SvcUtil.Extensions" /codecustomization:"XXX.CRM.Util.SvcUtil.Extensions.EntityCodeCustomizationService, XXX.CRM.Util.SvcUtil.Extensions"
```

The config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="url" value="https://XXX.api.crm6.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"/>
    <add key="domain" value=""/>
    <add key="username" value="XXX"/>
    <add key="password" value="XXXX"/>
    <add key="solution" value="XXXX"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="configConsoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener">
          <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Error" />
        </add>
        <add name="fileListener"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
   <sharedListeners>
      <add name="fileListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="CrmSvcUtil.log"/>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have two questions
What is causing this error?
How can I get the file tracing working?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to pull too many entities in one go. [Here's](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmshop/archive/2012/03/22/extending-crmsvcutil-filtering-the-generated-classes) an example to modify the codewriter file to include the Account entity only. You could use it as a starting point to filter out other entities.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly it has to be one of your code extensions.  You can run CrmSvcUtil from the command line, and then attach the debugger, and set break points within VS to diagnose.

You can read how to turn the teaching on [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx#bkmk_enabletrace).

Comment: thanks but I already have console tracing working. I want to get file tracing working.

Comment: Does it not contains a CrmSvcUtil.log file in the directory?  If your still having issues, you can see if the EarlyBoubdGenerator, an XTB plugin that I wrote, works.